# Adding a new page in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Quite new to Ruby on Rails and I am stuck on probably an easy task. Basically I am working on a colleague's app and need to add an additional page that shows users how the app works. I have already written the HTML and styles. I just don't know how to exactly add it to Rails and configure the routes properly. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**First** make sure that your colleague did not already create a controller to handle static pages. Look under `app/controllers` for controllers titled anything similar to `directories_controller` or `pages_controller`, etc. If he/she has, follow the pattern your colleague already set up (you might want to ask him/her for guidance at that point). If there is not static pages controller like that, then follow the advice below.

You can create a controller named something like `PagesController` that defines methods that match a route. For instance, your additional page might be called "help", in which case you can define a controller like so:

```
class PagesController < ActionController::Base
  def help
    # put any code here that you need 
    # (although for a static view you probably won't have any)
  end
end
```

Then you'll want to create a new folder under `app/views` titled `pages`, and you can add your static page there (app/views/pages) with a `.erb` extension. Using a `.erb` will allow your new page to use the default layout.

Finally, you'll need to add this controller to `routes.rb` in `(config/routes.rb)` to tell rails where to look for the `/help` page:

```
match '/help' => 'pages#help'
```

Comment: whats the easiest way to append a stylesheet to these pages?

Comment: You can pull in all your stylesheets the way you do normally, i.e. use <%= stylesheet_link_tag ..%>

Comment: Rails 4 complains about the `match` route when running `rails g controller pages`. `get '/about' => 'pages#about'` works.

Answer (score 19):

### Static pages

If your pages are truly static(nothing dynamic in them), you can drop them in the `/public` directory, and they will be directly accessible.

A file in `../public/help.html` will be accessible at `http://yourdomain.com/help.html`

### Semi static pages

If you want to use your layouts but just provide static content, you can make a controller, routes and views for that as follows.

```
# static_controller.rb
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render params[:page]
  end
end

# towards the end of routes.rb
get "/:page" => "static#show"
```

And make your views in `app/views/static`. You can use just plain html or erb as well. A view called `help.html.erb` will be available at `http://yourdomain.com/help`

Any view file you create under `app/views/static` will be available without modifying your routes or controller.

Comment: That's great, what if I want the page to take the CSS styles and rules from other existing pages, furthermore what if I also want to add it to the core navigational menu. Do I also need to create a layout for any reason? Apologies for so many questions!

Comment: You do not need to create a layout but you may want to, it is useful. If you link your CSS file in the layout, it will automatically apply to all your pages.